# Artisan server no Laravel com php 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5, artisan

Criei um projeto com framework Laravel 5.0 pelo composer, para rodar o projeto uso o comando **php artisan serve**, porem, verifiquei que a versão do php usada nesse servidor é a 7, tenho instalado o php 5.6 no computador e gostaria que o artisan rode com o php 5.6 em vez  do 7, tem como ?

Como a versão do Laravel é a 5, ele esta dando problema com o php 7 e por isso quero fazer essa mudança, só para continuar meus estudos com o Laravel!

Comment: qual problemas?

Comment: O problema é no composer ou no Laravel?

Comment: Não tenho como postar o erro agora, mas ocorre um erro quando submeto um formulário POST, pesquisei pelo erro e entendi que o erro acontece pq o Laravel 5.0 não funciona corretamente com o php 7, por isso quero ver uma forma de mudar a versão php nesse servidor.

Comment: [Nessa documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation), diz que só é possível rodar no 5.6.4 ou superior

Comment: Esse link é para a versão 5.4 do Laravel, estou usando a versão 5.0(https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation) pois estou seguindo um exemplo de um curso, pretendo refazer o projeto para uma versão mais nova depois de concluído, por isso quero ver se consigo rodar o php 5.6.
Tentei setando a versão php no .htaccess na raiz e na pasta public mas não funcionou, o phpinfo() continua informando que é php 7.